# Android Searchview crashes when more than one element in item

Tags: android, listview, fragment, searchview

I am using the search view to filter in a custom listview.  I have this working when only one textview is used, however if I add an additional one (which I don't require it to be searched) then it crashes the app.

```
 mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.salespartsList);
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.typeFindSalesPart);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            mListView.setFilterText(query.toString());
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
            return false;
        }
```

XML item file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp">

<TextView
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/itemID"/>
<ImageButton
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/itemAddBtn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    />
```

Comment: can you add crash log?

Comment: hello, I am having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution, or how did you get around this? thank you